# Error opening file (/home/vaibhav/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:553) in openCV

Tags: opencv

I am using OpenCV to display a video 
my code is as

```
#include<opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include<cv.h>
#include<opencv/cv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<cvaux.h>
#include<cxcore.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<highgui.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
CvCapture* capture;
cvNamedWindow( "video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); 
capture = cvCreateFileCapture("/home/vaibhav/program/c/w.avi");
IplImage* frame;
while(1){
frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
if( !frame ) break;
cvShowImage( "video", frame );
char c = cvWaitKey(33);
if( c == 27 ) break;
}

cvReleaseCapture( &capture );

cvDestroyWindow( "Webcam" );

return 0; }
```

The program compiles but it gives error when try to run it

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Eclipse

```
warning: Error opening file (/home/vaibhav/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:553)
```

Answer (score 15):

to clear up some confusion here:

the error means, that it could not find or open your *Video* file. (either file not found, or codec not present)

"/home/vaibhav/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:553" is just the location of the code, where the error is thrown.

(and please, don't use the deprecated c-api any longer, they stopped developing it like 5 years ago, switch over to the c++ one. )

Comment: what should i do please tell me

Comment: the code is worked fine in skm PC what is the problem with my

Comment: I am getting the same error - although there is possibility that my cause could be a possible different issue, but since this was never resolved I have downgraded this clarification since it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Very annoying (opencv 2.4.9). But what worked for me was passing the absolute file name (avi or mpeg), i.e whole path.

E.g.:

```
char* fileName = "D:/myVideos/video.avi"
...
VideoCapture capture(fileName );
```

Comment: The author of the question if on Ubuntu, and already pass full path, so the answer does not seems to fit to his problem

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 64 bit with Visual Studio 2013. This answer solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If using absolute path, add double slash to path as below.

```
data = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\Data\MyVideo.mp4')

data.isOpened()
```

> Out[11]: False

```
data = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\\\Data\\\MyVideo.mp4')

data.isOpened()
```

> Out[13]: True

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I did two things (I'm using Python 2.7.9 on Windows 10):

First, add this folder to your Path variable:

> C:\opencv\sources\3rdparty\ffmpeg\

And this file `opencv_ffmpeg300.dll` must have the correct OpenCV version. For example, for me it's 3.0.0, so you need to change it for yourself.

Next, make sure to add an extra backslash slash in your video path:

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture ('C:\Temp\\bouncingBall.avi')
```

Python has some special characters, so if there's only one backslash, it would interpret it differently and thus throw an error. You can see more here:

> https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Hence the double backslash.

Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: That may be solution for Windows, but not for Linux, where slash usually used for all paths

Answer (score 1):

After having the same issue, I added one more header, `opencv/ml.h`, which is for machine learning. With this header and the Path variable `C:\opencv\sources\3rdparty\ffmpeg\` your code works on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error if the video is not present in the folder. So, just put the video at a place where you don't need to give a long path which you are doing currently (just to see that your program can work). For example, i have placed my video just outside the "source folder", so i just write `capture = cvCreateFileCapture("video.avi");`

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue, but the problem is I used the wrong resolution.

change

```
rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.58:554/h264/video.sdp?camera=13
```

to default solved it. (without indicating the resolution parameter)

```
rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.58:554/h264/video.sdp
```

BTW Device: EVO-05 Mini

Answer (score 0):

I just used double quotes instead of single quotes using the entire video path and it worked for me! (on windows)